# How to set UK only products in BigCommerce for UK based store?

Tags: content-management-system, e-commerce, product, bigcommerce, theming

I am currently working on a UK based BigCommerce store and would like the option of setting products to only be available for sale in the UK, is this possible out of the box?

If not, has anyone managed to successfully do this through Theme Customisation?

I am currently using the Cornerstone Light theme, ideally I would like to include a 'UK Only' checkbox on the 'Add Product' page.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Controlling product visibility by country isn't a feature that's available out of the box, but this is something you can customize.

We're in the process of deploying a new `{{settings.country_code}}` property to the Stencil page context that would help you build out that kind of conditional logic. The `country_code` property outputs the country code of the shopper, according to the BigCommerce GeoIP service. So you could do:

```
{{#if settings.country_code '===' 'GB'}}

//do something - show the product, etc.

{{/if}}
```

This change has already rolled out to some stores, and should be available on all stores within the next few days, so keep an eye on our [changelog](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/changelog) for that announcement.

Comment: Thanks @KarenWhite, it wasn't just me who wanted this.